# Show a child's Matrix within a Structure

Tags: matrix

I want to show a child entry and can so:

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('products') %}

    {% switch entry.level %}
        {% case '1' %}
            {# level 1 #}
            <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>

        {% case '2' %}
        <li>    
            {# level 2 #}
            <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>

        {% case '3' %}
        <ul> <li>
            {# level 3 #}
            <h4>{{ entry.title }}</h4>
            </li>
            </ul>
        {% case '4' %}
            {# level 4 #}
            4
            </li>
    {% endswitch %}

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but I can't get a matrix field to show for the child entry, using:

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrix %}

            {{ block.intro }}

{% endfor %}
```

within any of the cases?

Comment: `{% for block in entry.myMatrix %}{% if block.type == 'intro' %} {{  block.intro }} {% endif %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Seems like that should be an answer instead of a comment, @Nutmeg. :)  Would get my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, user2569

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrix %}
    {% if block.type == 'intro' %}
        {{ block.intro }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yep thats it great!